# How to create Regex pattern to delete multiple substrings from a string in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a requirement to identify two patterns in a String, and if exists, i need to remove the substrings. Currently my code is below where I'm removing the substrings in two steps. I want to create a single Regex to identify "A," or "S," if exists, to replace with empty string.

My code:

```
if (charCode === characteristicsCode.SERIAL_NUMBER) {
                charValue = charValue.replace(/[(A,)]/g, '');
                charValue = charValue.replace(/[(S,)]/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe `|` operator works as an `or` in regex, so this:

```
charValue = charValue.replace(/[A|S]/g, '')
```